# email encode tag not working

Tags: email, encode

A client is complaining about an increase in SPAM so I'm looking into using the "encode" tag  on email addresses on the site. All email addresses are generated from channel entries from a text field within a Grid field cell.

I use this code in my template...

```
{facility_contact_info} <!--grid tag pair -->
{encode="{facility_contact_info:email}" title="Email Us"}
{/facility_contact_info}
```

I get this output on the front-end...

```
<span data-eeencemail_jsuwadycop="1"><a href="mailto:yo@email.com">Email Us</a></span>
<script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/var out = '',el = document.getElementsByTagName('span'),l = ['>','a','/','<',' 115',' 85',' 32',' 108',' 105',' 97',' 109',' 69','>','\"',' 109',' 111',' 99',' 46',' 101',' 114',' 97',' 99',' 104',' 116',' 108',' 97',' 101',' 104',' 109',' 103',' 109',' 64',' 76',' 65',' 108',' 101',' 100',' 65',':','o','t','l','i','a','m','\"','=','f','e','r','h','a ','<'],i = l.length,j = el.length;while (--i >= 0)out += unescape(l[i].replace(/^\s\s*/, '&#'));while (--j >= 0)if (el[j].getAttribute('data-eeEncEmail_PuAkdwoAKM'))el[j].innerHTML = out;/*]]>*/</script>
```

So besides the span tag with the data-attribute, the email address looks normal in the html. Did I do something wrong, is this a bug? Does "encode" even work anymore? Thanks for any info!

Comment: Is the encode tag between the grid field tag pair?

Comment: It is, I used the field name tag pair

Comment: Oh woops, I just noticed the script tag that was added below the email address. So I assume that script worked and that is why the readable email is in the email link? or should that look different?

Comment: Mike, this looks correct to me.